# Is calling environments in R computationally expensive?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I have a master user-defined function with many inputs. The master function calls a user-defined function, which calls another, which in turn calls another, and so on, each time using a smaller subset of the inputs.  I came up with two ways of passing the inputs to lower level functions:

1. manually, and
2. having each lower level function getting the inputs from the master function.

Solution 1) is typing intensive, and I suspect not what a more experienced programmer would do.  Solution 2) seems neater, but it takes much longer to run.  So I have two questions: A) Why does solution 2) take more time?  B) Is there an even better solution than either of these that reduces manual work by the programmer and is computationally efficient?  This kind of programming scenario has come up for me in my biology research, as well as in coding up statistical methods, so I assume this a common problem that others have solved.

I have included a simple example (adding 5 numbers) of the two solutions below, along with timing.

```
# Solution 1)
f0 <- function(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4){
  val <- a0 + f1(a1=a1,a2=a2,a3=a3,a4=a4)
  return(val)
}

f1 <- function(a1,a2,a3,a4){
  val <- a1 + f2(a2=a2,a3=a3,a4=a4)
  return(val)
}

f2 <- function(a2,a3,a4){
  val <- a2 + f3(a3=a3,a4=a4)
  return(val)
}

f3 <- function(a3,a4){
  val <- a3 + f4(a4=a4)
  return(val)
}

f4 <- function(a4){
  val <- a4
  return(val)
}

# Solution 2)

g0 <- function(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4){
  vars <- list('a0','a1','a2','a3','a4')
  env <<- environment()
  val <- a0 + g1()
  return(val)
}

g1 <- function(){
  for (i in get('vars',env)){assign(i,get(i,env),environment())}
  val <- a1 + g2()
  return(val)
}

g2 <- function(){
  for (i in get('vars',env)){assign(i,get(i,env),environment())}
  val <- a2 + g3()
  return(val)
}

g3 <- function(){
  for (i in get('vars',env)){assign(i,get(i,env),environment())}
  val <- a3 + g4()
  return(val)
}

g4 <- function(){
  for (i in get('vars',env)){assign(i,get(i,env),environment())}
  val <- a4
  return(val)
}

# Timing
t0 <- Sys.time()
replicate(1e4, f0(1,2,3,4,5))
t1 <- Sys.time()

tt0 <- Sys.time()
replicate(1e4, g0(1,2,3,4,5))
tt1 <- Sys.time()

# Time: Solution 1)
> t1-t0
Time difference of 0.2921922 secs

# Time: Solution 2)
> tt1-tt0
Time difference of 0.953675 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass around a named `list()`, or even create your own class based on a list. This is more-or-less how most models work in R: an `lm` object is a big list and there are lots of functions (`predict`, `summary`, `coef`, `AIC`, `plot`, etc.) that use whatever parts of the object that they need.

```
# Solution 4)
h0 <- function(arg_list){
 arg_list$a0 + h1(arg_list)
}

h1 <- function(arg_list){
  arg_list$a1 + h2(arg_list)
}

h2 <- function(arg_list){
  arg_list$a2 + h3(arg_list)
}

h3 <- function(arg_list) {
  arg_list$a3 + h4(arg_list)
}

h4 <- function(arg_list) {
  arg_list$a4
}


h0(list(a0 = 1, a1 = 2, a2 = 3, a3 = 4, a4 = 5))
# [1] 15
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to worry too much about exact dependencies. If `h2` calls `h3` and you edit `h3` use another piece of the list, you don't have to also edit `h2` to pass through the right argument since you're passing the whole object around.

Imagine how annoying it would be if you had to call `summary.lm` with exactly the pieces of a model that are used by summary and nothing else, instead of `summary(my_model)` you'd have `summary(rank = my_model$rank, resid = my_model$residuals, df_resid = my_model$df.residuals, w = my_mod$weights, ...)` and on and on for half or more of the elements of the model!

Answer (score 2):

Use `...` to pass parameters to the subsequent functions:

```
f0 <- function(a0, ...){
  val <- a0 + f1(...)
  return(val)
}

f1 <- function(a1, ...){
  val <- a1 + f2(...)
  return(val)
}

f2 <- function(a2, ...){
  val <- a2 + f3(...)
  return(val)
}

f3 <- function(a3, ...){
  val <- a3 + f4(...)
  return(val)
}

f4 <- function(a4){
  val <- a4
  return(val)
}

f0(1,2,3,4,5)
#[1] 15
```

Regarding A): Each function call costs time. And I think `assign` in particular is not very fast.

Comment: I wish I could click the check mark to this answer too.  This was equally helpful as the answer I marked as the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, solution 1 is probably easier to maintain, since each function is clear about what it is supposed to do.  The time taken to understand your code in the future will be less.

A generalised "best" solution is difficult; in this case it is trivially just `a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5`, though what the real functions are and how they interact will greatly affect your solution.

As to why solution 2 takes so long, it isn't just looking up variables in an environment, you are doing lots of getting and assigning.

I also don't think the function is doing what you think it is doing, since `vars` isn't stored in the environment `env`.

You could consider storing the variables in the global environment like this:

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 2
a3 <- 4
a4 <- 8


h1 <- function(){
  a1 + h2()
}

h2 <- function(){
  a2 + h3()
}

h3 <- function(){
  a3 + h4()
}

h4 <- function(){
  a4
}

h1()
```

Comment: It turns out that `vars` was stored in the execution environment of `g0`, which is what I was going for.  I checked by including the command `print(ls(env))` after `env <<- environment()`.  I think that's because `<<-` reaches up into the calling environment of `g0` and then renames the execution environment of `g0`. It would be simpler to have placed `vars` in the global environment, as you suggested, but in my actual problem (too specific to be useful to others), I have parallel runs for different initial parameters, and I was worried they could mess each other up.

Comment: Or did I get something wrong?  I just realized that my code could never have worked if `vars` wasn't stored in `env`, because I used the command `get('vars',env)`.  So I'm confused by what you meant about `vars` not being stored in `env`.